# Printing 2d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying print the array I've created below.

***NOTE: this is only a portion of my code that I extracted, so any commentary on anything needed before this portion is unnecessary.***

```
String [][]myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"},{"chair", "bench", "stool"}};

for (int i= 0; i < myList.length; i++)
{
    for (int j= 0; j < myList.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[i][j]);
    }
}
```

However, the issue I'm having is that the array print as a list, but I want it to print as:

```
Cat      chair
Dog      bench
Mouse    stool
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, thanks for identifying that issue, any input on how to go about fixing it?

Comment: @AlexisH change `myList.length` to `myList[0].length`

Answer (score 3):

```
String[][] myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"}, {"chair", "bench", "stool"}};
for (int i = 0; i < myList[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.length; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%-8s", myList[j][i]);
    }
System.out.println();
}
```

The outer loop (i) iterates through the columns (0, 1, 2).
The inner loop (j) iterates through the rows (0 and 1).
We use printf to format the output with a width of 8 characters for each element, using %-8s as the format specifier. This ensures that each element is printed in a column of the specified width.
After printing each column, we add System.out.println(); to move to the next line to create the desired format.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, if I run your code, all I see is this.

```
catdogchairbench
```

It is just jamming each word together *(and it looks like you are missing your `mouse` and your `stool`?)*.

In order to answer your question, we need to deal with the several bugs that are here. Your problem is buried underneath 2-4 other problems.

First order of business is to clean up the formatting here. We can do that by adding an empty call to `System.out.println()`.

```java
String [][]myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"},{"chair", "bench", "stool"}};

for (int i= 0; i < myList.length; i++)
{

    for (int j= 0; j < myList.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[i][j]);
    }
    
    System.out.println();

}
```

Now, your output is like this.

```
catdog
chairbench
```

This is an improvement.

Next, we want whitespace in between the words. We can use the tab character (`'\t'`) to create that whitespace.

```java
String [][]myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"},{"chair", "bench", "stool"}};

for (int i= 0; i < myList.length; i++)
{

    for (int j= 0; j < myList.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    
    System.out.println();

}
```

Here is the output.

```
cat     dog
chair   bench
```

Also an improvement.

Next, let's get back those missing elements -- `mouse` and `stool`.

In order to do that, we must first understand what happened to them. You correctly inserted them into your 2-d array, so that is not the issue. However, you are incorrectly ***fetching*** them from the array. Here is where that problem is.

Let's refactor your array creation a little, so that we can better see it's shape.

```java
String[][] myList =
    {
        {"cat",   "dog",   "mouse"},
        {"chair", "bench", "stool"}
    }
    ;

for (int i= 0; i < myList.length; i++)
{

    for (int j= 0; j < myList.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[i][j] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

So, your array has 2 rows, and 3 columns. We can clearly see that now. So, when you iterate through your array via the for loops, your for loops need to know about and iterate through those rows and columns correctly.

The way most people do this is by having a for loop for each component. That is, a for loop for your rows, and then another for loop for the columns in that row.

Let's refactor your code to make that clearer.

```java
String[][] myList =
    {
        {"cat",   "dog",   "mouse"},
        {"chair", "bench", "stool"}
    }
    ;

for (int row = 0; row < myList.length; row++)
{

    for (int column = 0; column < myList.length; column++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[row][column] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

Now, we can clearly see what the indices represent. It's no longer `i` and `j`, but a `row` and a `column` within the specified row.

Understanding that, let's look back at the for loops again.

Your `row` is looping from `0` all the way up to `myList.length`. Well, how long is `myList.length`? It is `2`, because, as we saw earlier, `myList` has 2 rows, so the value of `myList.length` is `2`.

But what about your `column`? It is ***also*** looping from `0` all the way up to `myList.length`. But `myList.length` is supposed to represent the number of ***`rows`***, not the number of ***`columns`***!

So, how do we fetch the number of columns? You get that by asking the length of ***the specific row you are on***. Your 2-d array has a length, but each row on your 2-d array also has a length. The reason why is because each element in your `myList` array is another array! And each array has a length. Thus, the number of columns = the length of the specific row.

But how do we represent that in your code?

Well, you do it like this. Instead of saying `myList.length`, you say `myList[someIndexValueHere].length`. Of course, we need to replace `someIndexValueHere` with an actual index value. That index value will be the row you are currently on. So, instead, it would be `myList[row].length`. This will give you the number of columns in the row specified by the index `row`.

```java
String[][] myList =
    {
        {"cat",   "dog",   "mouse"},
        {"chair", "bench", "stool"}
    }
    ;

for (int row = 0; row < myList.length; row++)
{

    for (int column = 0; column < myList[row].length; column++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[row][column] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

Here is the output now.

```
cat     dog     mouse
chair   bench   stool
```

Now, things look a lot better.

Now, we still have not solved your original problem. That was because we had to fix all of the bugs that were in the way. Let's solve your requested problem now.

Essentially, what you seem to want is for the above output to be "turned sideways". Meaning, it sounds like you want something like the following instead.

```
cat     chair
dog     bench
mouse   stool
```

If so, then this is a little tricky, but can definitely be done.

First, the way we are currently going is we are going to each row, then fetching all of the columns on it and printing them out.

To get this new output, we will have to reverse this process. Instead of going to each row and fetching each column, ***we now need to go to each column, and fetch each row on it***.

Luckily for you, your array has a special property -- all of the rows on your array have the exact same number of columns! If it was not for this fact, this problem would be much harder to solve.

But since we know that all the rows have the same number of columns, that means we can use the size from any row, and it will be the same size as every other row!

So, let's acknowledge that fact, and replace our call to `myList[row].length` to `myList[0].length`. We can get away with this because, the `0` row has the exact same number of columns (the same length!) as any other row on `myList`!

```java
String[][] myList =
    {
        {"cat",   "dog",   "mouse"},
        {"chair", "bench", "stool"}
    }
    ;

for (int row = 0; row < myList.length; row++)
{

    for (int column = 0; column < myList[0].length; column++)
    {
        System.out.print(myList[row][column] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

Now, we can make one simple change to solve your original problem -- just swap your for loops!

```java
String[][] myList =
    {
        {"cat",   "dog",   "mouse"},
        {"chair", "bench", "stool"}
    }
    ;

for (int column = 0; column < myList[0].length; column++)
{

    for (int row = 0; row < myList.length; row++)
    {

        System.out.print(myList[row][column] + "\t");

    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

If we run that, here is our output.

```
cat     chair
dog     bench
mouse   stool
```

Your problem is now solved. Let me know if there are any questions.

**EDIT** - To improve the answer, we could use `System.out.printf()` to help us with formatting. However, in order to use this, we need to know how long the longest element in your 2-d array is. Looking at it, we can see that the longest element is 5 characters long, so anything above 6 would work. But again, you either need to know that ahead of time, or figure out before you start printing. Here is the code refactored to use the new method.

```java
String[][] myList =
    {
        {"cat",   "dog",   "mouse"},
        {"chair", "bench", "stool"}
    }
    ;

for (int column = 0; column < myList[0].length; column++)
{

    for (int row = 0; row < myList.length; row++)
    {

        System.out.printf("%-7s", myList[row][column]);

    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

As for an explanation of how the function works, I will link to the answer by @WJS that explains it much better.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77152445/10118965

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this.  Use [System.out.printf()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) to format the output. Note this this will only work for rectangular arrays as it uses the number of columns of the first row for all rows.

- `"%-7s"` - the `7` is the field width and the `-` says to left justify the string in that field.

```
String [][]myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"},
                     {"chair", "bench", "stool"}};


for (int col = 0; col < myList[0].length; col++) {
    for ( int row = 0; row < myList.length; row++ ) {
        System.out.printf("%-7s ", myList[row][col]); 
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
cat     chair   
dog     bench   
mouse   stool
```

Answer (score 0):

## Challenges

Trying to achieve exactly your desired result, you have two challenges:

1. Printing the subarrays vertically
2. Printing it in a nice table-looking way

### 1. Printing the sub-arrays vertically

From your gut feeling, you want to iterate over the outter array and do something. But here you want to process the 1st item of all subarrays together, then the 2nd items of all subarrays, then the 3rd items and so on...

Therefor **you have to figure out what's the longest-subarray?** That's how long you'll have do your outter loop, because that is how many lines you'll have to print!

Now you can loop over all subarrays at once. But they may not all be equally long, so **always do null-checks** to verify if an element exists.

### 2. Printing it in a nice table-looking way

Ensuring all table cells have an equal width is easy (see other answers). `System.out.printf("%-6s", "abc");` will make all cells be 6 characters wide.

But depending on the strings in your array, you might need wider cells or maybe smaller ones to not waste space. **Calculate a reasonable cell width.**

## Solution

1. Figure out the longest subarray
2. Calculate the right cell width
3. Print the table

```java
String [][]myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"},{"chair", "bench", "stool"}};

// Figure out longest subarray
int longestArray = 0;
for (String[] array : myList) {
    if (array.length > longestArray) longestArray = array.length;
}

// Calculate the right cell width: find the longest string + add 2 chars for padding
int cellWidth = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myList[i].length; j++) {
        if (myList[i][j].length() > cellWidth) cellWidth = myList[i][j].length();
    }
}
cellWidth += 2;

// Print the table
for (int i = 0; i < longestArray; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.length; j++) {
        if (myList[j].length > i) System.out.printf("%-" + cellWidth + "s", myList[j][i]);
        else System.out.printf("%-" + cellWidth + "s", "");
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");
}
```

Output

```
cat    chair  
dog    bench  
mouse  stool
```

This **works for any number of subarrays and any number of items in them**.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... the issue I'm having is that the array print as a list, but I want it to print as: ..."*

Determine the width for each column, additionally the longest list.

```java
String [][]myList = {{"cat", "dog", "mouse"},{"chair", "bench", "stool"}};
int max = 0, widths[] = new int[myList.length];
String[] strings;
for (int i = 0, n = myList.length; i < n; i++) {
    widths[i] = maximum(strings = myList[i]);
    if (strings.length > max) max = strings.length;
}
```

```java
int maximum(String[] s) {
    return Stream.of(s).mapToInt(String::length).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Then, create a *[format-string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* for the row.
I'm adding *+2* to create space between the columns.

```java
StringBuilder fs = new StringBuilder();
for (int v : widths) fs.append("%%-%ds".formatted(v + 2));
```

Finally, build a *String* array for the corresponding elements, and apply the *format-string*.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
String[] row;
for (int i = 0, j; i < max; i++) {
    row = new String[myList.length];
    for (j = 0; j < row.length; j++)
        row[j] = i > myList[j].length - 1 ? "" : myList[j][i];
    s.append((fs + "%n").formatted(row));
}
```

Output

```
cat    chair  
dog    bench  
mouse  stool
```

Here is an example using a set of randomly generated values.

```java
Random r = new Random();
String strings[], myList[][] = new String[4][];
for (int i = 0, j, n1 = myList.length, n2; i < n1; i++) {
    strings = new String[r.nextInt(5, 20)];
    for (j = 0, n2 = strings.length; j < n2; j++) {
        strings[j] = r.ints('a', 'z' + 1)
                      .limit(r.nextInt(4, 10))
                      .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf((char) x))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
    myList[i] = strings;
}
```

Output

```
eoiigbu    eaglbxp    uiou       eygdnizf   
bfkcmid    snlz       vkbkqdo    obfxwtax   
xtxmo      nqtaoxijq  nlorcz     wpwdhk     
dwtdihj    tnsxp      zjeszm     vfeasklyj  
wsmgwegr   tolsnxauk  immxl      trbwlmxft  
lhejlvqh   wfhh       efwkdri               
bjiltokvt  hsprvsfpu  muoqp                 
nmerh      jfkuhr     ycylr                 
mmtcun     mgrj       lunarw                
jlnicv     faapyhjb   vlsqz                 
nehy       nfnmtdxai  yzxrivxn              
kiace      oorrj      jfbfgeo               
           hpzaaa     fwmpqcjbi             
           lxvnnqieo                        
           iqujzwnv                         
           hjjz                             
           dthlgtip                         
           oggqr                            
           dbpbr
```

Comment: You're using some ideas/features than may not be  familiar to the OP (e.g. `StringBuilder`, max string length to compute proper width format, `formatted`, etc).  You may want to add some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String [][]myList = {
            {"cat", "dog", "mouse"},
            {"chair", "bench", "stool","stood"},
            {"chair", "bench", "stool","stood","ascefq","efwef"},
            {"chair", "bench", "stool"},
            {"chair", "bench"},
            {"chair", "bench", "stool","stood","ascefq","efwef"}
            };
    
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i< myList.length; i++)
    {
        if(myList[i].length > max)
                max = myList[i].length;
    }

    System.out.println(max);
    
    for (int column= 0; column < max; column++)
    {
        for (int row= 0; row < myList.length; row++)
        {
            if(myList[row].length <= column)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%-8s","");
                    continue;
                }
                
            System.out.printf("%-8s",myList[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

With this solution you need less loop and still you will get the accurate result for any nxm array.

Actual logic is in the below part.

```
         if(myList[row].length <= column)
            {
                System.out.printf("%-8s","");
                continue;
            }
```

This loop is checking if the length of the row is less than or equal to the current column (as we are doing column iteration), means if row length is less or equal then we need to add space else add the string.

Hope it helps.